# What if any is the advantage of taking a bulking supplement over just having pure whey protein after a gym session?

Tags: nutrition, strength, protein

I'm attempting to understand if I should be using something other than whey (isolate) protein shake after my gym workouts (weight lifting and core strengthening).

There are lots of specific products advertised both on TV, at the gym and at the supplement store that have names like Bulk or hydroxycut as well as many, many more.

My question is: Is the science in on whether these other products have some advantage over "just" taking a straight 100% protein powder mixed with pure water?

I'm not an elite bodybuilder, just looking to stay fit an healthy and ensure I don't lose any lean muscle mass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To build muscle mass you need an excess of calorie intake, over the calories you are burning.  Bulking products will give you maybe 300-400 extra calories per shake in your diet which can be benefit in building muscle mass faster.  However you may also put on more fat than you would with a more pure protein shake.  It depends on your goals.

For strength or bodybuilding perhaps a bulking shake would be better, and for less strength orientated athletic performance a more pure shake may be preferable, hope that helps.

Comment: Yes thanks. I mainly wanted to make sure suc products were not in some way offering overall superior protein nutritional value straight after exercise. I want cut up so unlikely to use them